# Updating progress bar after user selects an item from array

Tags: swift

I am trying to update the progress bar after the user selects the desired value.
Values are taken from model and assigned to the label:

```
let volumeArray = [20, 50, 100, 150, 200, 250, 300, 330, 350, 400, 450, 500, 600, 700, 800, 900, 1000, 1500, 2000]
```

Custom progress bar code:

```
let center = view.center

let trackLayer = CAShapeLayer()

let circularPath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: center, radius: 100, startAngle: -CGFloat.pi / 2, endAngle: 1.5 * CGFloat.pi, clockwise: true)
trackLayer.path = circularPath.cgPath

trackLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
trackLayer.lineWidth = 10
trackLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
trackLayer.lineCap = .round
view.layer.addSublayer(trackLayer)

shapeLayer.path = circularPath.cgPath

shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.systemBlue.cgColor
shapeLayer.lineWidth = 10
shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
shapeLayer.lineCap = .round
shapeLayer.strokeEnd = 0

view.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
```

But how can I make sure that the progress bar is updated when the user selects a value. For example, from an array     `let volumeArray = [20, 50, 100, 150, 200, 250, 300, 330, 350, 400, 450, 500, 600, 700, 800, 900, 1000, 1500, 2000]`
But how can I make sure that the progress bar is updated when the user selects a value. For example, the user selected the number 100 from the array. The maximum value that the user must type, for example, is 2000. And based on the maximum value and the value selected by the user, the progress bar is updated by the corresponding percentage. I wrote a function

```
    func updateProgress() {
    if progressBar.progress != 1 {
        progressBar.progress += Float(milileters2.volumeFromMilimetersVC / 10)
    }
    shapeLayer.strokeEnd = progress
}
```

But unfortunately, it does not work. I would be grateful for any help since I am still a beginner

UPD. Data is taken from another ViewController

```
    var addDrinks = AddDrinksViewController()
    var drinksToMainVC: [String] = []

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    let vc = segue.destination as? MainViewController
    vc?.delegate = self
    vc?.addVolume(volumeFromMilimetersVC)
    vc?.addedDrinksArray.append(contentsOf: drinksToMainVC)
}

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    volumeFromMilimetersVC = volume.volumeArray[row]
    drinksToMainVC.append(drinks?.imageName ?? "nil")
}
```

Attached gif. As you can see, a value is selected from Picker View, which is then successfully written to the label, but the round progress bar is not updated.

[image]

Comment: What does your progress bar have to do with volumeArray or the selection that the user makes?

Comment: @ElTomato Data is taken from another ViewController  `func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
        volumeFromMilimetersVC = volume.volumeArray[row]
        drinksToMainVC.append(drinks?.imageName ?? "nil")
    }`

Answer (score 0):

In the function updateProgress, it is not shown where progress variable is getting updated. Progress variable can be updated as below.

let volumeArray = [20, 50, 100, 150, 200, 250, 300, 330, 350, 400, 450, 500, 600, 700, 800, 900, 1000, 1500, 2000]

let volumeMax = volumeArray.max()
//strokeEnd needs to be between 0 and 1, 2000 will correspond to 1 and others as a fraction of 1
let progress = CGFloat(milileters2.volumeFromMilimetersVC)/CGFloat(volumeMax!)
shapeLayer.strokeEnd = progress